# Horizontal scrolling with scrollLeft property not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, horizontal-scrolling

before i explain whats wrong: i know a very similar question has been asked but i cant fix it with that guys answer. :/

i am trying to build a horizontal slider from scratch with a "wheel" event.

The HTML setup

```
<div class="slide-container">
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.frontpage-slider--elem {
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Javascript: (Its inside a class, i am working with the "scroll" method.

```
   ...

   scroll(event) {
           if (event.deltaY > 0) {
               event.preventDefault()
               this.scrollDistance += 25;

               this.sliderContainer.scrollLeft += this.scrollDistance
               console.log(this.sliderContainer.scrollLeft += this.scrollDistance)

           }
       }

   ...

const slider = new Slider(sliderContainer, sliderElements)

sliderContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
    slider.scroll(event);
})
```

The Slider is scrollable and it worked with margin-left and subtract it by 25px, but i red that its bad practice, so i try it with scrollLeft and i run out of ideas what could cause it.

The `this.scrollDistance` does get add up but the slider does not move an inch.
Maybe i have a thinking error but i cant figure it out on my own.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some way you can provide to replicate this? One problem I can see is you're adding the value of `this.scrollDistance` to `left` two times one in console log as well. Please see **[`shorthand assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)**

Comment: @mandy8055 the console,log is only there to see if the scrollDistance gets added which it does.
https://codepen.io/LukasKrojer/pen/RwEmXOO
Here is a pen i created, removed the unecessary stuff, if this is what you are asking for?

Comment: sorry for bad class names, i acutally just was curious to write the javascript for this one

Comment: _"the console,log is only there to see"_ - but you are _not_ only logging a value there, you are _manipulating_ that value at the same time. You are performing the same addition operation _twice_ there, where it should only be once.

Comment: i see, i will try it later, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your slider container doesn't introduce a scrollable area without preventing flex child element growing or shrinking.

Try something like this

```js
const sliderContainer = document.querySelector('.slide-container');

sliderContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
  let deltaY =event.deltaY;
  sliderContainer.scrollLeft += deltaY;
})
```

```css
.slide-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: scroll;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  gap: 30px;
}

.frontpage-slider--elem {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
   <div class="frontpage-slider--elem"></div>
</div>
```

basically you're preventing the auto width adjustments by applying

`flex-wrap: nowrap` to the parent slider container
and `flex: 0 0 auto` to the slider(flex) items.
Also, you can use `gap` instead of `margin` in a flex layout context.

Comment: hey man, thank you for your solution but it still does not work. I dont get any errors or anything. In my Codeeditor it tells me "'deltaY' should probably not be assigned to 'scrollLeft" but as i said: no errors are thrown.
Code after that line does get executed tho and the event.deltaY does have a value of 128 but it does not scroll :(

Comment: @Hauskamel we're not assigning deltaY to scrollLeft . Could it be you're  missing the `+` in `sliderContainer.scrollLeft += deltaY ` ?

Comment: no, 100% not, checked it like 100 times.
I just changed it to style.marginLeft and it works as it should. i have absolutely no clue what else i should try.

Comment: it was a css problem. i had a position absolute on a parent div which caused it. :')